# Real integral evaluating as indeterminate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Mathematica evaluates the following integral as:

```
In[1]:= Assuming[p \[Element] Integers && p > 0, 
 Integrate[Sin[x]*Cos[x]^p/(Cos[x] + 2), {x, 0, Pi}]]

Out[1]= -2^p Beta[2/3, -p, 1 + p] + ((-1)^ p Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 - p, 2])/p
```

However, when I evaluate the resulting expression, I encounter a complex infinity.  For example, for `p = 3`:

```
In[2]:= -2^3 Beta[2/3, -3,  1 + 3] + ((-1)^3 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 - 3, 2])/3

During evaluation of In[96]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered. >>    
Out[2]= Indeterminate
```

Did I make a simple mistake in `In[1]` that is causing this problem?  Certainly $\sin x\cos^p x/(\cos x  + 2)$ is real and finite over the whole real line, for $p\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What happens if you append `// FullSimplify` to the integral within `Assuming[]`?

Comment: Interesting.  Adding `FullSimplify[]` within `Assuming[]` yields `ComplexInfinity`.  But how could that be?  For example, replacing `p` by `3` inside the integral gives a real result: `Integrate[Sin[x]*Cos[x]^3/(Cos[x] + 2), {x, 0, Pi}] = 26/3 - 8 Log[3]`.

Comment: Anyway... if I input only the integral, and I extract the expression inside the resulting `ConditionalExpression[]`, I get `(Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + p, 2 + p, -1/2] + (-1)^p Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + p, 2 + p, 1/2])/(2 (1 + p))`, which certainly is sensible for positive integer `p`.

Comment: Great 0x4A4D, this works, but where did I go wrong in `In[1]`?

Comment: I really don't know. Sometimes, the software just does the darndest things...

Answer (score 2):

If you plot the real parts of each half of your integral together

```
Plot[{Re[-2^p Beta[2/3, -p, 1 + p]], Re[((-1)^p Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 - p, 2])/p]}, {p, 0, 10}]
```

you'll see that each half goes to infinity in opposite directions, so the two singularities must cancel each other. Mathematica is stumbling over combining the two separate singularities exactly. There is no problem doing so if you plot the real part of the whole integral,

```
Plot[{Re[-2^p Beta[2/3, -p, 1 + p] + ((-1)^p Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 - p, 2])/p]}, {p, 0, 10}]
```

which means that it is a question of numerical precision. This is made clear by evaluating

```
Re[-2^p Beta[2/3, -p, 1 + p] + ((-1)^p Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 - p, 2])/p] /. p -> 2.9999999
```

which returns a finite value of -0.122232, versus adding another nine,

```
Re[-2^p Beta[2/3, -p, 1 + p] + ((-1)^p Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 1 - p, 2])/p] /. p -> 2.99999999
```

which returns an indeterminate value.